# Browser's Developer Tools

Tags: developer-tools

I'm experiencing a headache of a situation. I've been reading some ebooks online, and due to security measures, the website has locked the files, making it impossible to download.
However, I'd like to save some pages for my personal use. Usually, under developer tools, I can save the image, but I've encountered an unusual issue. When I save it, the image is split into 20 square boxes and appears upside down.

Could you please assist me in overcoming this issue? Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4koQf.png)

I have no idea what i can do to overcome it.